# Getting Value from array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

To get the value from `var_dump`:

```
mymeta_url_group => 
 0 => string(39) "a:1:{s:10:"mymeta_url";s:8:"You rock";}" 
 1 => string(40) "a:1:{s:10:"mymeta_url";s:9:"Yeah Sure";}"
```

I have used:

```
$urls= get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mymeta_url_group', false );

 foreach ( $urls as $url) 
 { 
         echo $url["mymeta_url"];
 // You Rock
 //Yeah Sure

 }
```

Now since I have added repeater and sorter option in backend new var dump shows:

```
mymeta_url_group => 
 0 => string(102) "a:1:{s:10:"mymeta_url";a:2:{s:11:"cmb-field-0";s:8:"You rock";s:11:"cmb-field-1";s:11:"Nope Maybe ";}}" 
 1 => string(100) "a:1:{s:10:"mymeta_url";a:2:{s:11:"cmb-field-0";s:9:"Yeah Sure";s:11:"cmb-field-1";s:9:"Won't you";}}"
```

Now How can I get Values "You rock" "Nope Maybe ""Yeah Sure""Won't you" extending my previous solution.

PS if I do `var_dump($url["mymeta_url"]);`
The output is

```
Arrayarray(2) { ["cmb-field-0"]=> string(8) "You rock" ["cmb-field-1"]=> string(11) "Nope Maybe " } Arrayarray(2) { ["cmb-field-0"]=> string(9) "Yeah Sure" ["cmb-field-1"]=> string(9) "Won't you" }
```

Comment: change boolean `false` to `true` in `get_post_meta`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `get_post_meta()` is supposed to do, but maybe this will give you some ideas:

```
<?php

/* Setting up data */

$data = array (
  'a:1:{s:10:"mymeta_url";a:2:{s:11:"cmb-field-0";s:8:"You rock";s:11:"cmb-field-1";s:11:"Nope Maybe ";}}',
  'a:1:{s:10:"mymeta_url";a:2:{s:11:"cmb-field-0";s:9:"Yeah Sure";s:11:"cmb-field-1";s:9:"Won\'t you";}}'
);

$urls = array();

foreach ($data as $s) {
  $urls[] = unserialize ($s);
}

/* Retrieving data */

foreach ($urls as $url) {
  foreach ($url['mymeta_url'] as $u) {
   echo "$u, ";
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you echo $url["mymeta_url"]["cmb-field-0"];does the same thing.But I am using repeater so I can not just hard code ["cmb-field-0"]...["cmb-field-1"]...["cmb-field-2"]

Comment: @Ashraf: What if you loop over `$url['mymeta_url']?. I've re-written the code in my answer.

Comment: @Ashraf: Did you change the `boolean` in `get_post_meta()' as suggested earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
foreach($array as $array2) { //If it doesn't work change $array to $array['mymeta_url_group']
    $array2 = unserialize($array2);
    foreach($array2['mymeta_url'] as $line) {
        echo $line; //$line is the sentance you're looking for
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if will work since I had to reconstruct the array from the `var_dump()` output.

Comment: Thank you .But It did not work.Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work but that's the best I can do without the original array. Could you use the `serialize()` method to send me the actual array? I might be able to help you then.